# Ubuntu 14 shows on bootloader menu of 12 but does not boot

Tags: boot, bootloader

I have a tri boot system. Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12 on the 1st hard disk. I got a new hard disk (external) and installed Ubuntu 14.0 on it and updated the grub on Ubuntu 12, it was successful but when i select Ubuntu 14 on the bootloader menu it gives an error such as 'no such device' ' you have to laod the kernal first' 
I used this article for help

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-14-04-install-guide.html

Comment: How large did you make / (root) partition on external drive. Some BIOS and external drives do not boot if boot files are beyond a certain point on drive. Often better to have a smaller 25GB / fully inside first 100GB of drive and rest of drive as /home or data partition(s). Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: @oldfred Partition size was too large (470 gb). Okay i will try smaller size. But i dont understand last line, "post this....." i am not that advanced Ubuntu user.

Comment: That is just a terminal command to quickly show partitions & sizes. You can test to see if that is an issue just by using gparted on live installer and shrink / (root) to less than 100GB. It it then works you can either create /home and move /home to new partition, use space as data partition or if a new user it just may be easier to reinstall.

Comment: @oldfred i will reinstall the system. Also i did not specify /home to any partition when i installed it, is it necessary? How it works?

Comment: /home is optional as a separate partition. If using a small / (root) then may be worthwhile to have separate partition for /home. Depends on total size allocating to Linux.

Comment: @oldfred Tried with smaller partion size of 20GB as / (root), but it still says 'no such device' ' no such partition' ' load the kernel first'  and when i directly boot from the external SSD it says Bootmgr missing

Comment: Install this in live installer, and run the summary report. Post link it gives. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Also see jim frederick's response.

Comment: @oldfred paste.ubuntu.com/9597949

Comment: You have 12.10, not 12.04 LTS. So 12.10 is not fixable and should be updated if you want Linux on first drive. You have the 12.10 boot loader in the MBR of both drives. Probably better to use Boot-Repairs advanced mode and install a Windows boot loader to sda, and install the grub2 boot loader for 14.04 to the MBR of sdb. So not install to partition like you currently have. That cannot be used to boot. Although you show grub4dos which is the very old boot loader used by EasyBCD to chain to another boot loader in a partition. But grub2 should not be installed to a partition.

Comment: @oldfred Is there a way i could remove Ubuntu 12 keeping windows 7 intact and reinstall Ubuntu 14 in place of 12

Comment: Best to use Something Else and choose current / (root) as new root partition. It will auto find swap. You can erase Ubuntu partition and use empty space. Make sure you have backed up /home or any data you want to save. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Answer (score 0):

Download software called (Boot-Repair-Disk) from sourceforge.net and burn to dvd, BOOT to the repair disk. Allow system to fully boot. The screen will show a box that says BOOT REPAIR (repair the boot of the computer) Click on (Recommended Repair) you will have boxes open asking you pertinant Questions, one question will be about your external hard disk, answer questions with yes or no and let software do its thing, exit boot repair disk when it's done, and reboot system and your GRUB screen will give you the options you are looking for. Worked for me more than a few times. This software is FREE :-)